# PHP Compact() function returning a empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array containing to which I have created local variables from using the extract() function with the EXTR_PREFIX_ALL flag set. Afterwards, I called compact() on the new prefixed variables created by extract() but displaying the array created from compact() using print_r() gives an empty array(). Sample code follows:

```
<?php
$cities = array('City1' => "Chicago", 'City2' => "Boston");

extract($cities, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "new");
echo "City 1: {$new_City1} City 2: {$new_City2}" . "<br><br>";

$new_cities = compact($new_City1, $new_City2);
print_r($new_cities);
?>
```

I am using PHP version 5.6. **What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your current code, you're actually providing the values of each variables you're trying to `compact`, not the name of the variables. It acts like a variable variables behavior. In order to make it work properly, you provide the variable names as strings or in array form:

```
$new_cities = compact(array('new_City1', 'new_City2'));
// or
$new_cities = compact('new_City1', 'new_City2');
```

Here's the excerpt from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php#refsect1-function.compact-parameters):

> Parameters
>
> *varname1*
>
> `compact()` takes a variable number of parameters. Each parameter can be either a **string containing the name of the variable**, or an **array of variable names**. The array can contain other arrays of variable names inside it; `compact()` handles it recursively.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try

```
$new_cities = compact('new_City1', 'new_City2');
print_r($new_cities);
```

[For more info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)